# Is monotonic sigmoidal relation between p and X'B in logistic regression equivalent as logit[p] having linear relation with X'B?

Tags: regression, logistic

Is the requirement of monotonic sigmoidal relation between p and X'B in logistic regression equivalent as logit[p] having linear relation with X'B? X is the vector of independent variables and B is a vector of estimates.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sigmoidal"? Normally this is a qualitative term referring to any function whose graph has an "S" shape, and therefore is much looser than a linear relationship with the logit.

Comment: No. Simple counter-example: a logit on predictors $x$ and $x^2$ can define a bell-shape, i.e. a non-monotonic relationship. This is immensely useful in e.g. ecology in which abundance of organisms is often highest for some intermediate moisture, temperature, salinity, whatever.